# How to make matmenutrigger only working for right click event should not for normal click in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to prevent `MatMenuTrigger` in clicking Event:

In below code if I click right click the context menu than it will open but if I do normal click it also open the context menu. I want to open the context menu only if I do right click

```
<button mat-flat-button  #menuBtn2 (click)="(element.type)" 
     [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"  (contextmenu)="$event.preventDefault();someMethod()">
        {{element.name}}
      </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.html) link.The main thing is adding

```
<div style="visibility: hidden; position: fixed"
    [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x"
    [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y"
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu">
</div>
```